# Problema con Button y espacio sobrante en Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

quiero pedir su ayuda en base a estos 2 errores que tengo, se ven básicos pero no he podido solucionarlos. El primer error, es que el cursor o el puntero del mouse no me está tomando la función del button (que a todo esto es una imagen), y el segundo error, es que dicha imagen no me abarca todo el espacio del div, por lo cual queda espacio sobrante, he intentando solucionarlo modificando valores del padding, así como los márgenes pero nada, a continuación dejaré imágenes de lo explicado anteriormente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se visualiza lo que mencioné anteriormente, al momento de poner el puntero en el botón no realiza la acción de realizar un evento, el puntero sigue con su forma normal, mientras que dicho botón con su imagen de fondo, no alcanza a a tomar la forma del contenedor he probado ya con un width de 100% pero nada.

riesgos.component.html

```
div class="container-fluid text-center in mt-5 borde">
  <h1 style="font-size: 48pt">Riesgos</h1>
  <div class="box mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3 flex-nowrap scrollbar">
          <ng-template ngFor let-proyecto [ngForOf]="Proyectos" let-i="index">
              <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 tarjeta" style="margin-left: 55px; width: 420px;">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body-xs embed-responsive embed-responsive-9by16">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" [src]="proyecto.url" alt="">
                          <div class="card-img-overlay text-center" style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold;">
                              <p class="card-text mh-100 h-25">{{proyecto.nombre}}</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" style="padding: 20px; padding-right: 1px; padding-left: 1px; cursor: pointer;">
                        <img src="assets/img/riesgos/seleccionar.png" class="img-fluid"
                        style="display: block; width: 400px; cursor: pointer;"></button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </ng-template>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

riesgos.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-riesgos',
  templateUrl: './riesgos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./riesgos.component.scss']
})
export class RiesgosComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  Proyectos=[

    {
      nombre:"riesgo 1",
      url:"assets/img/riesgos/trabajo_altura.png"
    },
    {
      nombre:"riesgo 2",
      url:"assets/img/riesgos/izaje_carga.png"
    },
    {
      nombre:"riesgo 3",
      url:"assets/img/riesgos/trabajo_electrico.png"
    }
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

riesgos.component.scss

```
.in{
    img{
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }
    h1{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .box{
        width: 40%;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        .form-control-plaintext{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 2px solid white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        button{
            padding: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar las [plantillas de card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) de bootstrap para obtener el resultado deseado:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 48pt">
        Riesgos
      </h5>
      <div class="card border-0" style="width: 400px">
        <div class="card-body p-0 m-0">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.tooltyp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1900x920-8-beneficios-de-usar-imagenes-en-nuestros-sitios-web.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />

          <div class="card-img-overlay text-center h-25 mh-100" style="margin-top: 140px">
            <p style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger" class="">
              {{proyecto.nombre}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="subtmit" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer">
              Seleccionar riesgo
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
```